# Swift returns error "method 'beginTrackingWithTouch(_:withEvent:)' with Objective-C selector 'beginTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:' conflicts"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I got this error message after upgrade from XCode 6.2 to XCode 7.0.1.

> /Users/ZERO/Documents/Xcode/XXXXX/Library/SegmentedControl/SegmentedControl.swift:124:10:
>   Method 'beginTrackingWithTouch(*:withEvent:)' with Objective-C
>   selector 'beginTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:' conflicts with method
>   'beginTrackingWithTouch(*:withEvent:)' from superclass 'UIControl'
>   with the same Objective-C selector

My code:

```
func beginTrackingWithTouch(touch: UITouch, withEvent event: UIEvent) -> Bool {

    let location = touch.locationInView(self)

    var calculatedIndex : Int?
    for (index, item) in labels.enumerate() {
        if item.frame.contains(location) {
            calculatedIndex = index
        }
    }


    if calculatedIndex != nil {
        selectedIndex = calculatedIndex!
        sendActionsForControlEvents(.ValueChanged)
    }

    return false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The method it has the almost same signature is defined in `UIContol`.

```
beginTrackingWithTouch(touch: UITouch, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
```

**The difference is `event` parameter has been optional.**

So the compiler cannot distinguish them. .

If you'd like to override `beginTrackingWithTouch()` method, you can change the type of event `parameter` to `UIEvent?`, and add `override` annotation like following:

```
override func beginTrackingWithTouch(touch: UITouch, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    ...

    return false
}
```

Comment: i will try if first. btw, i cant use override.